# WINAPI WinMain returns 0 but the process hangs about in Windows background processes

Tags: c++, process, winmain

We have a suite of unit tests for our application, divided up into projects and individual executables, that are part of our build system. One of the executables has started hanging about even after completion which means it's holding onto some of our dlls and preventing other processes from modifying them (signing etc).
When I debug the exe, I can see that it exits the `WINAPI WinMain` method, returning 0, the application then removes itself from the Apps section of the processes in task manager and appears in the Background Processes section, and the debugger doesn't close.
I don't really know where to start with this one but what might be causing the process to hang about in the windows processes even though the WinMain function has returned successfully?

Comment: Just because you return from `WinMain` doesn't mean the whole process will close, there are exit-time destructors (entering the d'tor of every static instance) `WinMain` isn't even the first function to be called in the main thread, it's `WinMainCRTStartup` which is the default entry point for every EXE file, which can do a lot of initialization before you enter your first line of code. Please provide more information, such as source code, what test suite are you using, compiler version, etc.. there are so many ways for something like this happen...

Comment: ensure that the windows messages are being processed by that application, if there is a datat stuck in the process event queue, that might be causing the issue.

Comment: Does it have multiple threads?

Comment: In the debugger look at the threads and see what they are doing.

Comment: "debug the exe" not sounds good. you need debug version compiled first.

Comment: @stark usually when there're threads running if to quit from main there's alert dialog.